# Honda pilot 2003 model

Tags: honda, transmission, pilot

D light drive is blinking and gear dis-engage on motion also, auxiliaries gear 1&2 blinking. what are the causes and remedy to avoid damage.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Blinking D means you have a trouble code stored. Get the code read. That's your starting point.